# How to call ltm function using rpy package in python

Tags: r, python

I am trying the following code:

```
from rpy import *
r.library("ltm")

dat= #some data frame or matrix
r.ltm(r('dat~z1'))
```

> error coming is--- RPy_RException: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos)
>   : object 'dat' not found

Please tell me the right way to call [ltm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ltm/index.html) function using rpy library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try as a general approach using rpy2 and something along the lines of:

```
from rpy2.robjects import *
r("library('ltm')")
r.assign('r_var_name',py_var_name)
r("r_var_name<-as.desired.data.type(r_var_name)")
```

Then whatever commands you're doing to 'r_var_name' using 'ltm' package functions inside further r("blah") statements.

E.g. getting the coefficients for one of the ltm package examples:

```
In [30]: py_obj = r("coef(ltm(Abortion ~ z1, control = list(GHk = 20, iter.em = 20)))")
In [32]: py_obj
Out[32]: 
<Matrix - Python:0x4db0290 / R:0x52f04f0>
[0.188998, -0.256378, -0.367623, ..., 4.542567, 5.840821, 3.243826]
```

Comment: thanks @conjectures.

your following line helped me straightway--

r.assign('r_var_name',py_var_name)

i was able to run this with rpy package also. thanks a lot :)

But i am yet deprived from using rpy2 in windows7 64 bit. Do you know any good way to install rpy2 on windows7 64 bit ??